# django admin cache Admin.method results

Tags: django, templates

This Model admin list view with 300 records, if I run it as is it's fast, but if I add a method to change a value it would take a long time to finish.

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 300
    list_display=('data_rif',
                  'get_created',
                  )

    def get_created(self, obj):
        return User.objects.get(username=self.cod_operatore).first_name
```

It would make 300 duplicates query.
Is there a way to cache the results for get_created?

Answer (score 0):

Override your `get_queryset` method and use `select_related` or `prefetch_related`.

Comment: the result of get_created is not related to anything in the model. the cod_operatore it's a stored as string not relation.